# How to edit email name while delivering reports via Agents in OBIEE?

Tags: email, oracle11g, report, business-intelligence, obiee

I did the following:

> 1. I prepared an analysis in OBIEE using a Direct Database Request. I saved the analysis to the network folder.
> 2. I created an agent for the analysis, added the recipients and configured the agent so that it would send the report to the desired
>      recipients at a particular time everyday.

*Now the report is being delivered on time everyday, but there is a little problem with the publishing e-mail ID. The publishing e-mail ID is shown as*

Oracle Business Intelligence obieeIN@xyz.in

How do I change that e-mail ID or the publishing name.

**I want it to flash 'Reporting & Analytics' in the email.**

Answer (score 2):

The sender name for Agent emails is a Scheduler setting configured in Fusion Middleware Control.

1. Under the tree view to the left, navigate to Business Intelligence -> coreapplication.
2. Select the Deployment tab.
3. Within that, select the Mail tab.
4. Change the "Display name of sender"